# How to get the id for insertion in to a DB in WebApi using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Just experimenting with Azure & WebApi.

Have this model:

```
public class ModelClass
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Model {get;set;}
}
```

There is this method, which creates a new resource.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(ModelClass))]
public IHttpActionResult PostModelClass(ModelClass obj)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    dbContext.ModelClass.Add(bankModel);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = ModelClass.Id }, obj);
}
```

But, this forces me to supply a parameter called `id` which has to be unique.

How can I delegate this responsibility to the DB to create a new `id` ?

I can, for the moment, think of getting the last updated id from the database & then supply it to the obj.

But is there any cleaner or any inbuilt way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard circumstances (by convention `ID` is the primary key), `ID` property gets populated automatically by EF when you save changes to the database.

Comment: Ok, so I should use `[Key]` to decorate my property which has to behave as a primary key. Gotcha. Thanks

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed.: by **convention**, a field called `Id` or `(EntityName)Id` will *automatically* be considered the primary key by EF (unless you specify something else to be the `[Key]`). So you *can* add the `[Key]` attribute for clarity - but it's not absolutely needed